# download a file on ajax success electron, jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, electron

i connected electron, jsp for login, sign up. electron is front side(html,js), jsp(jsp, java) is server side.

now i'm trying to download a file from server to electron. 
(here i set a file (bullet01.png) for test.)

flow:

1. when user clicks a button(ajax get request)
2. server find file which from url parameter
3. success method gets result

myscript.js

```
function downloadClick() {

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8090/curriculum1.4/login_controller.jspx?cmd=downloadFile&bFile=bullet01.png',
    type: 'get',
    //dataType: 'json',
    success: function(resp) {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(resp);
  //window.open("C:\Users\CP\Desktop\테스트\core5.0.14\out\artifacts\unnamed\curriculum1.4\filedir\bullet01.png");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert("err")
    }
});
}
```

when i execute on jsp it downloads ok but from electron it doesn't download anything.

here is the code

```
public void downloadFile(ViewMeta view) throws IOException {
    DataSet input = view.getInputDataSet();

    HttpServletRequest request = view.getHttpServletRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = view.getHttpServletResponse();

    String bFile = new String(input.getText("bFile").getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");

    String filePath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/curriculum1.4/filedir");

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + bFile + "\";");

    File file = new File(filePath + "/" + bFile);


    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();

    byte b[] = new byte[1024];
    int data = 0;

    while ((data = (fileInputStream.read(b, 0, b.length))) != -1) {
        servletOutputStream.write(b, 0, data);
    }

    servletOutputStream.flush();
    servletOutputStream.close();
    fileInputStream.close();

}
```

test.html in electron

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = undefined;}</script>
<script  language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/myscript.js"></script>
<script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>

<body>


  <h1 class="signUpTitle">test page</h1>

  <!-- <input type="button" value="버튼" class="signUpButton"  onclick="showOk()" > -->
  <a onclick="downloadClick()">file</a>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your question. _jsp is server_ is not accurate. You may have a Tomcat server that renders Java Server Pages templates into HTML that are then sent the browser. Even then, those would have little to do with Electron as Electron uses JavaScript, CSS and HTML to produce cross platform applications. Are you suggesting that you have two identical apps: one written with JSPs and a completely different app written with Electron?

Comment: @RandyCasburn yes you're right I have twe apps one with jsp, another with Electron..

Comment: Ok. Would have to see how you are including jQuery into your Electron application and will need a better idea on what _from electron it doesn't download anything_ really means. Need to know about what is printed in the console of the Electron View window containing the HTML and the above JavaScript.

Comment: @RandyCasburn i added test.html which is main page in electron.
first, I made download function in jsp  because jsp is more practiced than electron to me. so i finished file download fucntion in jsp with html, jsp,java. 
after that i tried to convert html in jsp to html in electron. i think converting html file jsp to electron is easy, but I have a problem to connect each other. I think file download function in jsp is finished. but when i call that function from ajax in electron it doen't download a file

Comment: @RandyCasburn added console log